# Indy 10's IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL crashes Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-5

I just installed Indy 10.6.2.0 in Delphi 5 with help from the users here. It works fine for my current app, but either 10.6.2.0 has a bug or I still don't have it installed properly.

If I drop a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` on a new Form, in a new or current project, it crashes Delphi if the Object Inspector is on the Properties Tab. I can drop it when on the Events Tag, but as soon as I click on the Properties Tab it crashes Delphi 5.

I do use this component in a threaded unit but I create it in source since there is no form. Works just fine. Since I get lost in some of the Indy help files, I like to drop components on forms just to view their properties and property choices. But it worries me that I can't drop this on a form to view the properties.

I don't remember which other components, but there were some others that demonstrated the same problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I drop a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` on a new Form, in a new or current project, it crashes Delphi if the Object Inspector is on the Properties Tab. I can drop it when on the Events Tag, but as soon as I click on the Properties Tab it crashes Delphi 5.

This is a known problem that only affects Delphi 5 (other versions are fine).

[Issue #65064: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL stack overflow in Delphi 5](http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/65064)

The cause is unknown, and so there is no fix yet.  But, as you have already discovered, there is a viable workround - create the IOHandler object in code at runtime instead of dropping it on a Form at design-time.

> I don't remember which other components, but there were some others that demonstrated the same problem.

I am not aware of any other Indy components that suffer from this problem.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Tomorrow, well because it bothers me (not that if will ever be fixed) I will drop all id components because I knew there were others. Maybe with a complete list, it might help figure out the problem. Also, since you guys answered this question and I am new here, how do I show this question has been answered?